# NumberAnimation is not running after reloading or restarting in QML

Tags: animation, qml

I have a requirement to flash animate an Image inside of a Rectangle whenever a signal (warning signal) is coming from CAN. Animation is working fine when the signal is set to warning state and the animation stops when it goes back to normal state as expected
But when the warning signal is present and I restart my application , I see that the image is not flashing. But the animation.running property is true when I see the logs.

```
Rectangle {
    id: mainRect

    visible: warningState === normal || warningState === warning

    Image {
        id: warningIcon

        source: //path

        NumberAnimation {
            id: warnAnimation
            target: warningIcon; 
            property: "opacity";  
            from: 1.0; to: 0.0; 
            duration: 250; easing.type: 
            Easing.InQuad; loops: Animation.Infinite
            running: warningState === warning
        }
    }
}
```

when I print the logs on restart the state is warning and also warnAnimation.running was true but the icon was not flashing.
Can anyone help me on the same.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could consider delaying the `running` until your application is ready, for example:

```
NumberAnimation {
    id: warnAnimation
    target: warningIcon; 
    property: "opacity";  
    from: 1.0; to: 0.0; 
    duration: 250; easing.type: 
    Easing.InQuad; loops: Animation.Infinite
    running: loaded && warningState === warning
    property loaded: false
    Component.onCompleted: loaded = true
}
```